# How can I move slowly smooth object to be child of another object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
if(crate.gameObject.GetComponent<UnlockCrate>().HasOpened())
                    {
                        primaryTarget = navi;

                        var rig_f_middle = GameObject.Find("rig_f_middle.02.R");
                        navi.transform.parent = rig_f_middle.transform;
                        navi.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                        navi.transform.rotation = rig_f_middle.transform.parent.rotation;
                        navi.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.0005999999f, 0.0006000001f, 0.0006f);
                        primaryTarget = null;                       
                    }
```

This just change the navi position but instead I want it to move smooth slowly directly to be child of the rig_f_middle.

In the screenshot the NAVI is almost at the top in the hierarchy is a child of another object and it should be moving smooth slowly to the bottom selected rig_f_middle.02.R(in my code it's rig_f_middle).

[image: NAVI and rig_f_middle.02.R]

This way the NAVI will move to the Player hand and the Player will hold NAVI.

This is what I tried :

```
if(crate.gameObject.GetComponent<UnlockCrate>().HasOpened())
                    {
                        primaryTarget = navi;

                        var rig_f_middle = GameObject.Find("rig_f_middle.02.R");
                        StartCoroutine(MoveNavi(navi.transform, rig_f_middle.transform, navi.transform.position, rig_f_middle.transform.position, 0.1f));                        
                        navi.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.0005999999f, 0.0006000001f, 0.0006f);

                    }
```

Then in the Coroutine :

```
IEnumerator MoveNavi(Transform navi, Transform rig_f_middle, Vector3 a, Vector3 b, float speed)
    {
        float step = (speed / (a - b).magnitude) * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        float t = 0;
        while (t <= 1.0f)
        {
            t += step;
            navi.position = Vector3.Lerp(a, b, t);

            if(Vector3.Distance(a, b) < 0.05f)
            {
                navi.parent = rig_f_middle.transform;
                navi.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                navi.localRotation = rig_f_middle.parent.localRotation;
            }

            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
        }
        navi.position = b;
    }
```

The object NAVI is moving fine and then when the distance is less then 0.05f it's making it child but there are few problems :

- The NAVI after become child it's position and rotation never set to 0,0,0 I tried this :

  navi.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  navi.localRotation = rig_f_middle.parent.localRotation;
- When the NAVI is getting close and to hand there is kind of jump/glitch when it become a child.

If it needed I will add the completed script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once childed to the object, it will move with the parent. You can't gradually become a child. However, you can choose to not child initially, then smoothly move towards the intended parent's position and once the distance is less than 0.05 or something, you can child it.

You can smoothly move using Vector3.MoveTowards. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html

You can check the distance with Vector3.Distance. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html

Comment: I updated my question with what I tried, I'm using Coroutine and Lerp instead MoveTowards for some reason I didn't success with the MoveTowards. and also added the two problems I'm getting now.

Comment: You probably don't want to set the object's local rotation to the parent object's local rotation. If you set the object's local rotation to Quaternion.identity then it will 0, making it the same rotation as the parent. As for the jump/glitch that's likely because 0.05f units may be too far. But since you're using Lerp that's an easy fix. Instead of checking distance, just check if t >= 1.0f to know if it's finished.